# How can I get my bootstrap dropdown menu to work?

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

On the smallest resolution, the bootstrap dropdown menu isn't working. From my research, I thought adding the jquery files above bootstrap, but this did not work. Does anybody have any ideas? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4cq8.png)

Comment: can you create fiddle? paste the code rather than code as an image

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot you've provided, it seems to me like you're including jQuery, but not bootstrap.js (or bootstrap.min.js):

```
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```